# PHP - select a dropdown item through $_GET link

Tags: php

I'd like to select a dropdown item using the value in the link. I'll get this value through the `$_GET` method.

How to do it so?

Answer (score -1):

Your link is https:sitedomainexample.com/index.php?a=1

```
<form method="get">
    <select name="typeofice">
        <option <?php echo (isset($_GET["a"]) && $_GET["a"] == 1 ? "selected":"");?> value="double chocolate">Double Chocolate</option>
        <option <?php echo (isset($_GET["a"]) && $_GET["a"] == 2 ? "selected":"");?> value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
        <option <?php echo (isset($_GET["a"]) && $_GET["a"] == 3 ? "selected":"");?> value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
        <option <?php echo (isset($_GET["a"]) && $_GET["a"] == 4 ? "selected":"");?> value="caramel">Caramel</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe I explained myself not really clearly. What I want to achieve is that I pass a link with, following your example, www.google.com?icecream=doublechocolate and then clicking on it the dropdown is already compiled with Double chocolate